# How to use isProviderEnabled so it isn't highlighted in yellow with warning?

Tags: android, android-gps

I am trying to check if GPS is switched on. I want to peform this check before any other code runs. I have tried using many code examples, but every time and every where I use `isProviderEnabled` it highlights in yellow and warns of a potential NullPointerException. How can I remove this warning, and where should the code be placed?

```
final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) 
          getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
     /* some code   */
  }
```

[screenshot of error and highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDgGY.png)

Comment: Check to see if `manager` is `null` before calling `isProviderEnabled`. I do not know of any circumstances where `manager` would ever *be* `null` in this case, but the tools don't know that.

Comment: Tried that, no joy. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before using LocationManager check if it's non-null wrap the code block like this

```
final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) 
          getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  if(manager != null){
     if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
      /* some code   */
  }
}
```

Comment: Same error. Also tried `try...catch`. Driving me nuts! Thanks for responding.